# return_url of Stripe confirmPayment is getting called twice for one particular card

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments

Endpoint `return_url` provided in `confirmPayment` is getting called twice for the test card **4000002760003184**. We have checks to avoid multiple executions, but it is not working as they are called almost simultaneously.

Any suggestion on why this is happening for this particular card?

Comment: I tested with a Payment Element page using confirmPayment and only saw a single redirect to my return_url in the network history. There aren't many details in your post for the community to work off of, could you edit and add more specific information about the behavior that you're seeing?

Comment: It's August 2023 and I have am having the exact same problem with the same test card.  I am based in the UK and need this feature of verifying transactions called 3D secure.  The return_url is being called twice.  Needs to be once.  Please help Stripe.

Comment: Let me know if you found any better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Stripe, this is known behavior and we should use [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to confirm the payment rather than confirming based on return return_url.

If webhook is not feasible, see if [this](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-synchronously?platform=web#web-handle-next-actions) is helpful.